# writing if condition in htaccess file for url rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My htaccess code for URL rewrite is as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/myekc/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myekc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(css|images|js)/ 
RewriteRule "/t/pepsi/(.*)$" "http://192.168.0.175:68/$1" [P]
RewriteRule "^(.*(?:xampp|htdocs)/)(.+)$" "http://192.168.0.179/myekc/t/pepsi/$2" [R,QSA,L]
```

This works for 1 URI. I now want to write if condition, in such a way to write for multiple uri
Eg:

```
<If "req('uri') == '/t/pepsi/'">
RewriteBase "/myekc/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myekc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(css|images|js)/ 
RewriteRule "/t/pepsi/(.*)$" "http://192.168.0.175:68/$1" [P]
RewriteRule "^(.*(?:xampp|htdocs)/)(.+)$" "http://192.168.0.179/myekc/t/pepsi/$2" [R,QSA,L]
</if>
<If "req('uri') == '/t/coke/'">
RewriteBase "/myekc/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myekc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(css|images|js)/ 
RewriteRule "/t/coke/(.*)$" "http://192.168.0.175:68/$1" [P]
RewriteRule "^(.*(?:xampp|htdocs)/)(.+)$" "http://192.168.0.179/myekc/t/coke/$2" [R,QSA,L]
</if>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an explicit `<If>` condition here. With mod_rewrite, if you need a directive to apply to a different URL, you simply include that directive for the different URL by specifying the appropriate `RewriteRule` *pattern*. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*(?:xampp|htdocs)/)(.+)$ http://192.168.0.179/myekc/t/pepsi/$2 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myekc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(css|images|js)/ 
RewriteRule /t/pepsi/(.*)$ http://192.168.0.175:68/$1 [P]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myekc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(css|images|js)/ 
RewriteRule /t/coke/(.*)$ http://192.168.0.175:68/$1 [P]
```

Note that the `RewriteBase` directive can only be used once in the `.htaccess` file (the last instance wins and controls the entire file). But you aren't using at all in the directives you've posted, so I've removed it completely for now.

However, currently, these two rules do the same thing so can be combined:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myekc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(css|images|js)/ 
RewriteRule /t/(?:pepsi|coke)/(.*)$ http://192.168.0.175:68/$1 [P]
```

---

> I need if condition because, i want to set cookie value to each pattern. So that the value of the cookie will be the path "/t/pepsi/" and "/t/coke". If i use together, the last cookie value is considered. Example: Want to set `Header set Set-Cookie "mycookie=/t/pepsi/" "expr=-z %{req:Cookie}"`and `Header set Set-Cookie "mycookie=/t/coke/" "expr=-z %{req:Cookie}"`.

You still don't need an explicit `<If>` condition, since mod_rewrite allows you to set cookies, which is probably easier to use in this instance (since you are already using mod_rewrite to capture the path). For example:

```
RewriteRule (/t/(?:pepsi|coke)/)(.*)$ http://192.168.0.175:68/$1 [CO=test:$1:.example.com,P]
```

The `CO` (`cookie`) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive sets the cookie `test` (on the domain `.example.com`) to the value of the URL-path in the request (ie. "/t/pepsi/" or "/t/coke/").

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co

Comment: I need if condition because, i want to set cookie value to each pattern. So that the value of the cookie will be the path "/t/pepsi/" and "/t/coke". If i use together, the last cookie value is considered. Example: Want to set Header set Set-Cookie "mycookie=/t/pepsi/" "expr=-z %{req:Cookie}"and Header set Set-Cookie "mycookie=/t/coke/" "expr=-z %{req:Cookie}"

Comment: I've updated my answer with regards to setting a cookie to the URL-path.